# How to convert WrappedArray to string in spark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file which contain nested array as like below,

```
|    |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

I have used Spark to read json and exploded the array.

```
explode(col("list_of_features.geometry.coordinates"))
```

which  returns values as below,

```
WrappedArray(WrappedArray(WrappedArray(1271700, 6404100), WrappedArray(1271700, 6404200), WrappedArray(1271600, 6404200), WrappedArray(1271600, 6404300),....
```

But the original input looks like without WrappedArray.

something like,

```
[[[[1271700,6404100],[1271700, 6404200],[1271600, 6404200]
```

The ultimate aim is to store the coordinates without `WrappedArray` (may be as String) in csv file for Hive to read the data.

After explode is there any way to just the coordinates enclosed with proper square brackets.

Or can I use replace to replace the `WrappedArray` string value in RDD?

Comment: I don't know wrapped array, but you should be able to write a recursive function that returns you what you need. Maybe there is a cleaner option tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UDF` to `flatten` the `WrappedArray` and make it `String` value as

```
//udf
val concatArray = udf((value:  Seq[Seq[Seq[Seq[Long]]]]) => {
  value.flatten.flatten.flatten.mkString(",")
})
```

Now use `udf` to create/replace the column as

```
df1.withColumn("coordinates", concatArray($"coordinates") )
```

This should give you a `string` separated with `","` replacing the `WrappedArray`

**UPDATE:** If you wan in the same format as `string` with brackets then you can do as

```
val concatArray = udf((value:  Seq[Seq[Seq[Seq[Long]]]]) => {
  value.map(_.map(_.map(_.mkString("[", ",", "]")).mkString("[", "", "]")).mkString("[", "", "]"))
})
```

Output:

```
[[[[1271700,6404100][1271700,6404200][1271600,6404200]]]]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's flatten the entire coordinates , But I want to maintain the array levels by square brackets. This coordinates are latter used to draw polygon in the map. So maintaining the levels are needed.

Comment: Due to two level of flatten it will never maintain the level right as I mentioned in my post [[[[1271700,6404100],[1271700, 6404200],[1271600, 6404200]][132122,24433]]]

Comment: I guess As per the schema you provided two level of flatten should work.

Comment: Or you want like `[[[[1271700,6404100],[1271700, 6404200],[1271600, 6404200]][132122,24433]]] ` this as string. i.e with beackets ?

Comment: Yes you are right. to be more specific I want to store this data as string in hive instead of complex data types. But I would like to maintain the [ as it's from original data.

Comment: If possible could you help me to clarify why in spark 1.6 just casting to String works for nested array but in 2.1 it writes the values as "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData" which requires above udf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168904/discussion-between-william-r-and-shankar-koirala).